# How to add close button to inner.HTML text?

Tags: javascript

I have an inner.HTML text which will arise when an user uploads an image with invalid dimension.Now the thing is i want to have a close button in that error message.how can I achieve it.

Comment: Something like `innerHTML = 'Your message <button.....>x</button>';` ?

Comment: if my answer helped you please close the question and upvote the answer..

Answer (score -1):

You can give this  an id and than the button remove this id from the dom

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id=msg>
    write the msg
    <button onclick="$('#msg').remove();">X</button>
    
    </div>
```